# JetBrains IDEs code completion with . (dot)

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

JetBrains IDEs (now checked with PhpStorm) don't complete with dot. For example I am typing `win` and put `.` and it becomes `win.` whereas I would like it to complete to `windows.`. In R# for example it completes the way I want.

Comment: In PHP, where `.` is concatenation symbol .. it may create "false positive" situations. But if you sure in your choices -- just enable it in Settings (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion | Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys`)

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you. Post it as an answer, so I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option is disabled by default in PhpStorm. It was auto-enabled when it was introduced... but based on initial feedback it was decided to have it disabled by default.

Anyway:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Code Completion`
3. `Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys`

[image]